# Julia - Optim - Gradient per Observation

Tags: r, julia, gradient

I am developing an adhoc multinomial logistic model using Julia. 
It works fine (although I am sure it could be improved!)

I have written the likelihood function and use Optim to estimate the parameters and the standard errors.

I would like now to develop some robust estimates. Coming from R, I would be using the sandwich package. I did not find any equivalent in Julia. So I could develop something specific I guess.

For this I would need the value of the gradient for each observation (row). I do not find a way to do that using Optim. (When I use `gradient!(func, x)`, I get the sum of the gradients across rows, which is not what I am looking for)

Is there a way to do that using OnceDifferentiable or TwiceDifferentiable ?

Alternatively, is there a package equivalent to R Sandwich that would have escaped from my google researches?

The code I have developed so far:

```
LLIK_MNL = function(init::Array{Float64})
    b = init
    u1 = X1*b
    u2 = X2*b
    u3 = X3*b
    umax = max.(u1, u2, u3)
    umin = min.(u1, u2, u3)
    ucensor = (umax + umin)/2

    exu1 = exp.(u1 - ucensor)
    exu2 = exp.(u2 - ucensor)
    exu3 = exp.(u3 - ucensor)
    sexu = exu1 .+ exu2 .+ exu3 

    Pr=(choice1 .* exu1 + choice2 .* exu2 + choice3 .* exu3) ./ sexu
    LL = sum(log.(Pr))
    return -LL
end

func = TwiceDifferentiable(var -> LLIK_MNL(var), beta_ini)
opt = optimize(func, beta_ini)

est_MNL = Optim.minimizer(opt)
numerical_hessian = hessian!(func, est_MNL)
var_cov_matrix = inv(numerical_hessian)
temp = diag(var_cov_matrix)
t_stats = est_MNL ./ sqrt.(temp)
pp = 2 * cdf.(Normal(), -abs.(t_stats))
hcat(est_MNL, sqrt.(temp), t_stats, round.(pp, 4))
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to improve the readability of your code by adding some whitespace. Can you check whether I didn't introduce any mistakes?

Comment: BTW, in Julia it's more idiomatic to use `function LLIK_MNL(...) ...`. (In fact, it's a different thing, since it defines an actual function with one method, not just some anonymous value.)

Comment: Your code is not fully reproducible as `X1` etc. are missing (BTW: in Julia it is usually better not to use global variables but pass them as arguments to a function) are missing but I guess you could define `LLIK_MNL` to work on rows and then define a wrapper function that aggregates it. Then you could calculate the gradient for this function that is defined to work on one row. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for these tips and changes. I am changing the code accordingly. Sorry for not providing the data making it not reproducible. I did not want overcharge things with all the data.